# MVVM ViewModel project structure

Tags: mvvm, naming-conventions, naming

In my solution I have project with POCOs, View project, and view model project.
There are two types of ViewModels:

1. ViewModel per View Control(`Window`, `CustomControl`)
2. ViewModel per POCO (wrapper which also is inherit from `ViewModelBase`)

I want to separate all ViewModels into two folders, but I`m confused with their naming.
Can you suggest some variants?

Thanks.